# Reuse / Remember function return value in view

Tags: angularjs

Imagine the following situation:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in stuff" ng-show="getInfo(item) !== null">
    <div>{{getInfo(item).var1}}</div>
    <div>{{getInfo(item).var2}}</div>
    ...
</div>
```

I declared an `getInfo()` function inside my controller which returns some additional information for a given object.

Later, I use that information multiple times.

**How can this be written without calling my controller function `getInfo()` multiple times?**

Something like this would be nice:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in stuff" ng-define="info=getInfo(item)" ng-show="info !== null">
    <div>{{info.var1}}</div>
    <div>{{info.var2}}</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Is this possible without implementing additional directives?

Comment: You could add an info property to each one of your items which would eliminate the need to constantly call getInfo.

Comment: Why not store the results coming from `getInfor()` in an array and then use that array directly?

Comment: This is a simplified example. In my actual code I have two nested `ng-repeats` and `getInfo()` depends on both of them. Calling and appending `getInfo()` for each of them beforehand is also time consuming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ng-init`

```
ng-init="info = getInfo(item)"
```

*The ngInit directive allows you to evaluate an expression in the current scope.*
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. And ignoring `The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat` might even be appropriate for my use case.